# Org-mode: Recenter buffer to top when clicking on an org-agenda link

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

When right- or middle-clicking on a headline generated in the agenda, org will open a buffer with the file containing that headline. That headline will be centered in the buffer.

How can I make it so that clicking on an agenda link aligns the headline to the top of the buffer rather than the center?

I found that I could do this manually by customizing `recenter-positions` and then hitting `C l` (`recenter-top-bottom`), but I really would like this to happen automatically.

Comment: You should consider modifying `org-agenda-goto`, since it does not use a variable or argument to control recentering -- instead, it uses `(recenter (/ (window-height) 2))`  If we describe the middle-mouse-click with `describe-key`, we see that it triggers `org-agenda-goto-mouse`  If we look at that function, we see that it uses `org-agenda-goto`, and if we look at that function, we see a modification of said function would be required based on the foregoing line of code dealing with recentering.

Comment: To redefine an existing function, use `(require 'org-agenda) (defun org-agenda-goto (&optional highlight) "Go to the Org-mode file which contains the item at point." ...)`  Change the portion relating to recentering.  Or, if you are an anti-modification believer in the holy scripture `org-mode` source code, you can use the `org-agenda-after-show-hook` to recenter *again* using whatever you like -- note that this is technically inefficient considering that recentering could have been customized by modifying `org-agenda-goto`.

Comment: Redefining `org-agenda-goto` worked like a charm. Want to post that as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the function `describe-key`, we can trace `org-agenda-goto-mouse` to `org-agenda-goto`, and from there we can examine the function in the `org-agenda.el` library to see what makes it tick.  The re-centering command is hard-coded as `(recenter (/ (window-height) 2))`, which means it cannot be easily controlled by the user with an optional argument or by customizing a variable.  In general, functions an be redefined by `require`-ing the library followed by the newly defined function with the same name:  `(require 'org-agenda) (defun org-agenda-goto (&optional highlight) "Go to the Org-mode file which contains the item at point." ...)` Change the portion relating to recentering. The doc-string for `recenter` describes the available methods of controling the behavior of said function.

During the process of inspecting `org-agenda-goto`, we learned that `org-agenda-after-show-hook` is called at the tail-end.  A less efficient alternative approach to modifying `org-agenda-goto` would be to add new behavior to the aforementioned hook -- however, that would essentially call *again* `recenter` to fix the undesired previous call.